# Turn off trackpad scroll "momentum"

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad

So when I flick my fingers while scrolling on my trackpad, the page continues to scroll even after my fingers have left it. I don't like this, however, because then when I switch to a different tab in Chrome, by pressing `control + <number>`, it triggers the "zoom" command in chrome which is `control + <scroll>`. This causes the side effect of whever I switch to a new tab, the previous tab gets zoomed in. Is there a way to turn off this trackpad scrolling "momentum" or any other possible solution?

Comment: This is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253697). Please star it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do it, here are 2 via the command line:

```
xinput --set-prop --type=float "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" "Synaptics Coasting Speed" 0 0
```

Or the more succinct

```
synclient CoastingSpeed=0
```

Comment: do either of these persist between logins / reboots?

Comment: So.. on Ubuntu 14.10, it does persist between reboots... but not my trackpad doesn't work at all :-(

Luckily I have a touch screen. Unluckily, it doesn't work in chrome. I had to do lots of tab holding in order to get to this comment box.

Comment: well.. I don't know what I did, but somehow touching in chrome works now. Trackpad still doesn't work. Current amount of googling suggests a bug in the kernel. :-\

Comment: They do not persist between X sessions, let alone reboots. You would put these as lines in the X init scripts for your account.

Comment: Second option worked great for me.

Comment: `synclient CoastingSpeed=0` worked for me too, but it disables inertial scrolling completely at the OS level. Chrome should fix [the bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253697).

Comment: After 10 years none of these options work. No gui settings either. Horrible user experience.