# How can I disable continuous scrolling in ubuntu touchpad?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, scrolling

In Trusty Tahr (14.04 LTS) when I use two-finger scrolling in everywhere, say chrome and it  sensed the touch-pad for 1 second to go up or down for scrolling. The website  continued the scrolling for 3 or 4 seconds. And  when I press any key on my keyboard, it's supposed to know that I am use that key with scrolling (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scrolling cause to zoom out or in very very much). Is there any way to turn off or disable this bad function?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this one (and was answered): [Turn off trackpad scroll "momentum"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301766/turn-off-trackpad-scroll-momentum)

Running this command helps:

```
synclient CoastingSpeed=0
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore: "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"